# How can I automatically close stale issues in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, controls, version

Is there an out of the box feature to automatically close issues that have not had any activity for a specific period of time e.g. 4 weeks?

If not, what would be the best way to go about implementing this for my Group's issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not exist per se but you can prepare a script to run into a cronjob or similar tool, so you regularly clean these issues. The script could use the [GitLab Issue API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#list-issues), and check issue dates to determine whether to close a specific issue or not. The API has all the required tools for you to make this script with the described logic.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses the [`python-gitlab`](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab) package. It gets all group issues, adds a comment to those that have been inactive and closes them.

Only prerequisites are to

- get a `PRIVATE_TOKEN` and add it to your environment
- find out your group ID and add it below

```py
import datetime
import os

import gitlab


stale_before = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=28)

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(
    url="https://gitlab.example.com", private_token=os.environ["PRIVATE_TOKEN"]
)

group = gl.groups.get(123)  # your group ID
issues = group.issues.list(all=True, state="opened")

for issue in issues:
    updated_at = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(issue.updated_at).date()
    if updated_at < stale_before:
        print(f"Closing issue #{issue.iid} (last activity on {updated_at}).")
        issue.notes.create({"body": "Closing for inactivity."})
        issue.state_event = "close"
        issue.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familier with such option but you can look into Issues list and sort by created  or updated.